# Circular dependency, on Nestjs modules

Tags: nestjs, node-modules

I cannot access an injected dependency in the interceptor class so I deduced that there is a problem with the importing of some kind, If put the decorator `@injectable()` on the interceptor throws the app doesn't even start and says -> ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the LogsInterceptor (?). Please make sure that the argument LogsService at index [0] is available in the AppModule context. On the other hand if I remove it the app launches with no problems but when I call a method from service throws -> await this.logService.logRequestService(log);
^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logRequestService'), so I share both classes
interceptor:

```
import { CallHandler, ExecutionContext, Injectable, NestInterceptor } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable, catchError, map, tap, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { LogsService } from './logs-service';
import { ILogModel } from './ILogModel';


export class LogsInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private logService: LogsService) {}

  intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    next: CallHandler<any>,
  ): Observable<any> | Promise<Observable<any>> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    let responseStatus = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();
    let args: any = context.getArgs();
    let log: ILogModel;

    console.log('before');
    return next.handle().pipe(
      tap({
        next: (response) => {
          log = {
            ip: args[0].hostname,
            username: args[0].user.nombre_completo,
            tipo: args[0].method,
            path: args[0].originalUrl,
            query: args[0].query,
            params: args[0].params,
            body: args[0].body,
            response,
            statuscode: responseStatus.statusCode,
          };
          //let customers = this.logService.logRequestService(log)
          //console.log(log);
          this.logRequest(log);

          console.log('after');
          return response;
        },
        error: (error) => {
          console.log(error);
          log = {
            ip: args[0].hostname,
            username: args[0].user.nombre_completo,
            tipo: args[0].method,
            path: args[0].originalUrl,
            query: args[0].query,
            params: args[0].params,
            body: args[0].body,
            response: error,
            statuscode: error.status,
          };
          //this.logService.logRequest(log)

          console.log(log);
          console.log('entrado por error');
          return error;
        },
      }),
    );
  }
  async logRequest(log: ILogModel): Promise<void> {
    if (log != undefined) {
      console.log(log);
      await this.logService.logRequestService(log);
    }
  }
}
```

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DBConnection } from 'src/database/database.service';
import { ILogModel } from './ILogModel';

@Injectable()
export class LogsService {
  constructor(private _db: DBConnection) {}

  async logRequestService(log: ILogModel): Promise<any> {
    try {
      let response: any[] = await this._db.query(`data base request`)
      console.log(response);
      return response;
    } catch (error) {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to use this interceptor? What does your `AppModule` look like (as that's where the error is pointing to)

Comment: thanks @JayMcDoniel my error was that I wasn't importing LogService in AppModule. Logs are used globally and I was trying to importing it inside the logs module